# SamlResponse passes third-party signature validation but fails ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2 validation

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, saml-2.0, itfoxtec-identity-saml2

I am using `ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2.MvcCore` SAML2 SSO with an IBM commercial IdP server product. `<SamlResponse>` has a signed `<Assertion>` element, with no other signatures or encryption.

SSO authentication works as expected if I skip the `Saml2PostBinding.Unbind` call. However, project requirements and enterprise policies dictate that signatures must be verified.

When making the `Saml2PostBinding.Unbind` call, I can step through the ITfoxtec source code for the latest package release (4.10.4), and see it pass all the signature detection checks, correctly detect the signing cert, and detect and apply the signature algorithm (`http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256`) and the correct canonicalisation (`http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#`). Everything proceeds as expected until it executes this line of code:

```
return CheckSignature(Saml2Signer.Certificate.GetRSAPublicKey());
```

which is calling into standard dotnet crypto routines. It fails this call by returning false. Turning on symbol server source debugging, it is failing on this section of code in `System.Security.Cryptography.Xml.SignedXml.CheckDigestedReferences()`:

```
try
{
    calculatedHash = digestedReference.CalculateHashValue(_containingDocument, m_signature.ReferencedItems);
}
catch (CryptoSignedXmlRecursionException)
{
    SignedXmlDebugLog.LogSignedXmlRecursionLimit(this, digestedReference);
    return false;
}
SignedXmlDebugLog.LogVerifyReferenceHash(this, digestedReference, calculatedHash, digestedReference.DigestValue);
if (!CryptographicEquals(calculatedHash, digestedReference.DigestValue))
{
    return false;
}
```

because the `calculatedHash` **does not equal** the `digestedReference.DigestValue`.

Signing cert, intermediate certs and root cert are all valid, and explictly imported and trusted in the cert store on the repro machine (Windows 10 Business 21H2, 19044.3086 build, Windows Feature Experience Pack 1000.19041.1000.0).

The kicker is that the failing `<SamlResponse>` passes signature validation in the onelogin Validate SAML Response tool at https://www.samltool.com/validate_response.php. After it passes, I can even make onelogin fail it by changing a single character inside the `<Assertion>` element.

On the face of it, I would also not expect a mature IBM commercial IdP server product to misapply signatures.

**What I tried:**
I tried debugging the ITfoxTec code and the dotnet source code. I tried verifying the signature in an external tool.

**What I expected:**
I expected the signature to verify inside both ITfoxTec and the external tool.

**What resulted:**
What resulted was that the signature verified in the external tool but not inside ITfoxTec.

Comment: Do they have an overload of `CheckSignature` where it's not you to provide a cert but rather the cert is extracted from the SAML token and you just get a verification status and the information about the certificate used? If they have, it could be your chance to use it and make sure the certificate used at the server is really the one you use at the relying party.

Comment: Thanks Wiktor, that's a great suggestion. I'm not supplying any cert myself in code or config, so `Saml2Signer.Certificate.GetRSAPublicKey()` will either return what is in the SAML, or null, I suppose. I will try to dump the value of what it returns just before the `CheckSignature` call, to verify. And look for an overload too.


If I'm reading the Microsoft code correctly, the signature hash fail happens before it even tries to verify the signing cert.

Comment: Report back what you find out. Could be a problem in the way ITFoxtec handles the signature or even something odd down there in the SignedXml. You could try yet another SAML2 client library to validate the response so that it's not one true vs one false but rather a wider set of evidence.

Answer (score 0):

What .NET version are you running?

I'm wondering if the problem is related to [issue #156](https://github.com/ITfoxtec/ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2/issues/156), do you see the same problem in version 4.8.2?

Comment: Thanks Anders. I am using .NET 6, and the earliest version of ITfoxTec I could get to work with my own code was 4.1.1. That one has the same problem.

Comment: I will try 4.8.2 and 4.8.6 too, to rule issue #156 in or out.

Comment: Is it possible for you to run your code in .NET 7? There has been some XML updates which could have great importance.